# So, I have a html file and another one as well which has a navigation bar. So I want to link my html file to that navigation file. How do I do that?

Tags: html

I have a html file with navigation bars and all. I have another html file named about which I want to get linked with about in my navigation bar. Can someone help me with all detailed info.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @Ayushma show some code, what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not very clear to be honest but you'd usually want to navigate by implementing a controller, i suggest you do some research on it.
otherwise you could obviously do it the plain way, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)
BalusC's answer explains it well and you could apply this to your navigation bar.

if we're talking strictly html you could circle your Navigation text/button tag that you want to click with a `<a>` tag as so `<a href="/targetPage.html"><p>Target Page</p></a>` to open the page in the current tab or `<a href="/targetPage.html" target="_blank"><p>Target Page</p></a>` to open a new tab.

Comment: This is not a very clear answer. The HTML section of BalusC's answer is not relevant here as Ayushma is likely not using a form. The CSS section does somewhat answer it, but focuses on explaining how to make an anchor element look like a button

Comment: i inteded to lead him into exploring better ways of navigation and forgot to answer the question directly, Edited

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `<a>` tag. This will do what you want it to do.

I suggest [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) as a good resource